# How to consume non-REST WCF service for a hybrid mobile application?

Tags: node.js, wcf, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, ionic-framework

Am trying to develop a mobile application which will be **consuming an existing non-REST WCF service. What will be the best way to consume this service if i choose to develop the mobile application?** Am new to mobile development and will be open to any suggestions.

Few things about the application as such:

1. Its an existing web application which we will be migrating to mobile
   app.
2. The mobile app will need to have android/iOS versions so we are
   thinking to develop hybrid app in either XAMARIN or IONIC.
3. The data-source for the application will be an already existing WCF
   service.
4. We cannot rewrite or change the WCF service as we do not
   have the permission to do so.
5. Security is an important aspect in this application.
6. I have only the end points and not the entire project. [Cannot edit the web.config or alter the methods to return JSON]

Am not asking for complete solution here and just for the directions. Any thoughts/suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of these modules to consume the WCF https://npms.io/search?q=WCF or https://npms.io/search?q=SOAP, or create another service that wraps/proxies the WCF and converts it to a REST or maybe JSON RPC interface, maybe something like this: https://github.com/kmvi/JsonRpc.ServiceModel

Answer (score 0):

Consume that service in VS via Service Reference which generates proxy for you